# Who can find a necessary and suficient condition on an positive integer $n$, making $Aut\mathbb{Z}_{n+1}=\mathbb{Z}_{n}$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, automorphism-group

Who can find a necessary and suficient condition on a positive integer $n$, making $Aut\mathbb{Z}_{n+1}=\mathbb{Z}_{n}$? *Aut* means Automorphism group. This statement is true for n=1,2. However it is not true for all positive integer $n$.

Comment: Have you swapped $n$ and $n+1$?

Comment: $Aut(\Bbb{Z}_n)$ has order $\phi(n)$. More precisely: $Aut(\Bbb{Z}_n)\simeq \Bbb{Z}_n^*$. And $\phi(n)<n$ for all $n>1$. We have $\phi(n)=n-1$ iff $n$ is a prime. And in those case $Aut(\Bbb{Z}_n)\simeq \Bbb{Z}_{n-1}.$ Look up *primitive roots*.

Comment: I did swaped n and n+1. Now I have correct them.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$

Comment: $$\Bbb{Z}_n^*=\{\overline{a}\in\Bbb{Z}_n\mid \gcd(a,n)=1\}.$$ This is a group under multiplication. Any homomorphism from $\Bbb{Z}_n$ to itself has the form $\overline{x}\mapsto \overline{ax}$. This is an automorphism iff $\gcd(a,n)=1$. The composition of such automorphisms then is isomorphic to the product of the elements $a$.

Comment: So $Aut(\Bbb{Z}_{n+1})$ has $n$ elements if and only if $\gcd(a,n+1)=1$ for all $a=1,2,3,\ldots,n$ if and only if $n+1$ is a prime number. The fact that $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$ is cyclic is not trivial. Look up primitive roots for a proof.